# Is there a good way convert java class between relational database?

Tags: jdbc, relational-database

I want to build a web application using relational database and java as backend.

And I know I can define java class and use jdbc to CRUD columns in database.

However, I'd like to know if there's a way to convert database columns back to java class without using serialization?

Since all columns have clear defined fileds in relational database, I guess there might be a way to get the type and somehow fit it into java class.

Can anybody tell me if there's a way to convert database column to java class without using serialization?

Comment: How comes you never heard about object-relational mappers?

Comment: Thank you, I'll reconsider which way to do my application.